# простое Rest Api

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Передо мной стоит задача реализовать простое Rest Api используя платформу WordPress. Необходимо сделать аунтификацию пользователя, и сгенерировать токен доступа в зависимости от cUrl.( подробная задача реализована расшиернием PHP Phalcone https://olddocs.phalconphp.com/ru/latest/reference/tutorial-rest.html). Есть ли такая реализация в самом WP??? Либо подробный мануал по WordPress Rest Api??

Comment: У WP вроде из коробки есть API

Comment: Самих мануалов по настройке коробки маловато, именно под такую специфичную задачку. Поэтому вопрос и завис в воздухе...

Comment: Насколько помню всё работает сразу если не зарубить его через functions вот пара сайтов en: http://v2.wp-api.org 
ru: https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/rukovodstvo-dlia-nachinauschih-po-wordpress-rest-api/ en: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/#a-distributed-api

Comment: Маловато? А я уверен что ты про них ничего не знаешь https://codex.wordpress.org/ru:API_WordPress и конкретно reatapi https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/